# Remove Header/Footer from cart page Storefront theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I want to remove header and footer from the cart page in storefront woocommerce theme with the help of custom function or hook.

Can you suggest me which function i should use to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two ways. One is using CSS and another is using hooks. As you particularly asked about hooks then I will provide the code for the hooks.

You need to find out which hooks were used in header and footer of storefront theme. And then in storefront child theme, create a functions.php file (if does not exist, most probably it does exist) and then add the following code:

```
function remove_header_from_cart(){
    if( is_cart() ){

        remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'storefront_header_widget_region', 10 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_container', 0);
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_skip_links', 5 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_site_branding', 20 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 40 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_container_close', 41 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper', 42 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 50 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close', 68 );
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','remove_header_from_cart');

function remove_footer_from_cart(){
    if( is_cart() ){
        remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_footer_widgets', 10 );
        remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_credit', 20 );
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','remove_footer_from_cart');
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. However, in some cases, the child theme is also a third-party component that may receive updates, in which case the functions.php file is at risk of being override. If that's the case, use a custom plugin or a helper like https://github.com/woocommerce/theme-customisations which is a plugin made to "behave" like a theme/child theme extension. Hope this helps!